# Finding if values exists in previous n values of vector r

Tags: r

Am I missing a better way of doing this - or at least a way that allows to vary the window size?

Say I have a vector, v.

```
v <- c(T,T,F,F,F,F,F,T,T,T,T,F,F,F,F,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,F)
```

I wish to convert this vector such that FALSEs are turned to TRUEs if a TRUE appeared within the previous 3 elements. e.g. the F's at positions 3,4,5 would also switch to T's as there is a T at position 2. The F at position 6 would not.

Solution if only interested in a window of 3:

```
vlag1 <- lag(v)
vlag2 <- lag(vlag1)
vlag3 <- lag(vlag2)
ifelse(v==T|vlag1==T|vlag2==T|vlag3==T,T,F)
```

Gives the desired result:

```
 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

But what if we wanted to vary the window to e.g. 4 or 5 - is there a better way?

Comment: `embed` might be useful if you want to stick to base R.

Comment: @Henrik - thanks this is a good catch. My `ifelse` above does appear to give the desired result I give as does the `zoo` and `base` solution.  The `data.table` solution doesn't work in this case.   I really appreciate you noticing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with `rollapply` from the `zoo` package:

```
library(zoo)

rollapply(v,
          width = 4, align = "right", partial = TRUE,
          FUN = function(x) ifelse(TRUE %in% x, TRUE, FALSE))
```

Note that I have set `width = 4` here, not 3. In your question, you said you wanted to check the previous 3 elements. Width includes the ith element. So, if you want to base the result on the previous 3, you have to set width to 4. You also need to include `align = "right"` to look back from the ith element (the default centers on the ith element, and you can also look ahead with `align = "left"`).

Comment: or `rollapplyr(v, 4, any, partial = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a more manual solution:

```
# Input vector
v <- c(T,T,F,F,F,F,F,T,T,T,T,F,F,F,F,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,F)

# Size of the window
k <- 3

# Output vector
outp <- rep(F,length(v))

for(i in seq(length(v))){
  # Checking values on variable window
  aux <- v[seq(pmax(1,i-k),i)]
  # Writing on output vector
  outp[i] <- any(aux==T)
}

outp
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
n <- 3
r1 <- Reduce(`|`, shift(v, seq_len(n), fill = FALSE))
identical(r1, r2)
#[1] TRUE
```

where 'r2' is the OP's output from `ifelse`